# Cannot Interract with an Appended Element in JQuery

Tags: jquery, append

I have a `DIV` element.

```
<div id="testButton"> Test Button </div>
```

I'm gonna click on it, and then another element will be appended in Another `DIV` Element

```
$("#testButton").click(function() {

$("#testDiv").append('<div id="test">Test</div>');

});
```

Now I want to `Click` on the appended element to hide the first element.

```
$("#test").click(function() {

$("#testButton").hide();
});
```

But that doesn't work...

Comment: The title of the duplicate may be misleading, but they both boil down to "clicking on this thing that I added dynamically doesn't work". The answer is **event delegation**, and there are probably better examples of questions about it; however, I answered that one earlier today so it was the fastest to find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the element didn't exist on the moment of attaching event handler to it - it doesn't work.

You may use this solution instead:

```
$(document).on('click', '#test', function() {
    $("#testButton").hide();
});
```

Or, if there is some particular block already on a page - you could use more specific selector like

```
$('#testDiv').on('click', '#test', function() {
    $("#testButton").hide();
});
```